# Background Sync in iOS

Tags: ios, singleton, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `Sync` class which basically syncs the data to server in background.

The use of `Sync` class object is such that the View Controller from where I make a sync request on the `Sync` class object may get deallocated before the sync gets actually complete.

The problem I am facing here is the `Sync` class object gets deallocates too and hence the sync request never gets complete.

I thought of making `Sync` class as a Singleton but that would be more of abuse of the Singleton pattern.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep strong pointer to the object before starting operation:

```
__block StubClass *strongSelf = self;
```

And start method on it:

```
[strongSelf dataSync: ^... { //completionBlock
   strongSelf = nil;
}];
```

Or do it with semaphore:

```
__block StubClass *strongSelf = self;
dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[strongSelf dataSync: ^... {
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
}];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
strongSelf = nil;
```